# Control doesn't come back to application after uploading photo to Instagram

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, instagram

What I have done with my application:

**Implemented**

- In the application I code for Instagram integration in that I successfully open Instagram and upload an image to the Instagram server. Also I show the uploaded photo.

**Problem**

- After the in-app image shares through the Instagram integration (which is similar to Facebook integration), the control doesn't come back to my application

Is it possible to return control to my application after sharing a photo through Instagram?

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE and irrelevant for this question. You could be writing iOS apps in TextEdit as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, there is no solid way to tell another app to open yours at a certain point. The best you can usually hope for is convincing the app to attempt to open a URL which uses a custom schema you have registered with your app. I skimmed over the [instagram API documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/), and the only mechanism with a URL-based callback appears to be authentication (not passing an image over post-auth). You can explore the API more, to see if you can avoid the hand-off altogether, but I didn't see anything there about actually posting a photo on behalf of the user (seems like they are keeping that one to themselves).

Good luck!